# hexadecimal encoding/decoding functions in mysql

Tags: encoding

are there any hexadecimal encoding/decoding functions that mysql will recognize to avoid writing a whole algorithm out. base16_encode/decode does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MySQL  understands hexidecimal literals

> MySQL supports hexadecimal values, written using X'val', x'val', or 0xval format, where val contains hexadecimal digits (0..9, A..F). Lettercase of the digits does not matter. For values written using X'val' or x'val' format, val must contain an even number of digits. For values written using 0xval syntax, values that contain an odd number of digits are treated as having an extra leading 0. For example, 0x0a and 0xaaa are interpreted as 0x0a and 0x0aaa.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

Comment: Thanks, all this time I had no Idea there was a hex function, thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If this answer is useful, please upvote and/or accept :-)